# Can anyone help me out with block.io API for withdrawal of bitcoin from wallet?

Tags: api, bitcoin

I am trying to use block.io API, before few months I tried and implemented, it was working perfect, and now they have changed signed signature method, All APIs working correct, only withdrawal API not working, Response of curl is showing success, but says required more_signatures_needed , I don't know how to do this, Can anyone help me? I will be thankful.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         myPage.Text = readHtmlPage("https://block.io/api/v2/withdraw_from_addresses/");

```
   //fecth response
    String myUri = Session["myPagecc"].ToString();
```

//display response
        Label1.Text = myUri.ToString();

```
}
private String readHtmlPage(string url)
{

    String api_key = "myapikey";

    double amounts = "btcamount";

    String to_addresses = "receiveraddress";

    string FROM_ADDRESS = "myaddress";

    string NEWCODE = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);
    string priority="medium";
    String result = "";
    String strPost = "api_key=" + api_key + "&from_addresses=" + FROM_ADDRESS + "&to_addresses="+to_addresses +"&amounts="+amounts+"&priority="+priority+"&nonce="+NEWCODE;




    StreamWriter myWriter = null;

    HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    objRequest.Method = "POST";
    objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
    objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    try
    {
        myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
        myWriter.Write(strPost);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
    finally 
    {
        myWriter.Close();


    }

    HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr =
       new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        // Close and clean up the StreamReader
        sr.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

"status" : "success", "data" : { "reference_id" : "70ab0922cf036481533e7f345068c0bed36f9681d644d8", "more_signatures_needed" : true, "inputs" : [ { "input_no" : 0, "signatures_needed" : 1, "data_to_sign" : "3916022666e29882298d54c2c8f2ab3306cc4e774594f5db9", "signers" : [ { "signer_address" : "jhE397dsNaNLByJ8WV43emD1mhSpPtwDV", "signer_public_key" : "a34b48a3a18373020d8d96fb53b733d373cd3ba9b5bbfd2c9f8105c8939058130d", "signed_data" : null } ] } ], "encrypted_passphrase" : { "signer_address" : "NaNLmhSByJ8WV43emD1jhE397dspPtwDV", "signer_public_key" : "373cd3ba9b5bbfd2c9f8020d8d96fb53b733d373a34b48a3a18105c8939058130d", "passphrase" : "r20/Wyy5iTVFmpcmn1Y8JOMR8mP7jAqaBrMf2UOW2aEBQSQ1XfxpgonIyFLDOKkmuqH84sETSjXTFsl3dpo5niABB2rL69vnsLbS4DaXMw1o33NH0zgHyzdkAYmIoeGe85YVPMkrQsNhLrGQ6JUaubT+W3rIBxP7rCqYznnMnt8QxG4wu5LSh2EY8fja6AI1" }, "unsigned_tx_hex" : "010000000127d8d4654bc8cf69c9b1980c1afa67e51b5b28241ac080100000023220020200d0c2118ad382e8dab4f3c2ddf5ab8ca1d8ac3ffa3d910a0a2aa86cb69cb77bb62e2a7f12fbc8a699ffffffff076a914103ee4139219756a503842b0ad01000000000019caf5a381440b66bd81188ac64a401000000000017a9145af1577250a83928e306b35f8463047d72d9e3408700000000" } }

Comment: Instead of using a 3rd party api, you should consider using the Bitcoin Core JSON RPC

Answer (score 0):

Any solution for this please.

With Block.IO token withdrawal it seems we need to send some extra secure pins 
as per their doc:  https://block.io/api/simple/signing

Like to know how to send cURL to execute ?

Their sample cURL is not working: /api/v2/withdraw_from_addresses/?api_key=API KEY&from_addresses=ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,...&to_addresses=ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,...&amounts=AMOUNT1,AMOUNT2,...

response is:

```
{[status, success]}
{[data, {
  "reference_id": "24fe5a.....",
  "more_signatures_needed": true,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "input_no": 0,
      "signatures_needed": 1,
      "data_to_sign": "2498d....",
      "signers": [
        {
          "signer_address": "1H4.....",
          "signer_public_key": "037710.....",
          "signed_data": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "encrypted_passphrase": {
    "signer_address": "1H4...",
    "signer_public_key": "0377....",
    "passphrase": "fDCM0...."
  },
  "unsigned_tx_hex": "01000...."
}]}
```

if possible: expecting some sample in asp.net vb please